# XCode crashes when expanding the "Bundle React Native code and images" phase

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

[image]

I am following the [instructions](https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-updates/#final-steps-to-perform-in-xcode) to setup `expo-updates` for XCode. The last step requires modification in the `Bundle React Native code and images` phase. However, XCode crashes without any error report as soon as I expand the phase.

Additional Info:

- Mac Air (Apple M1 chip)
- XCode 12.4
- React Native 0.63.4

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that I do not have a `shellScript` property for the `Bundle React Native codes and images` phase. The solution is as follows:

Go to `project.pbxproj`, search for `Bundle React Native codes and images`, it should be the parts where you can see the properties such as `isa`, `buildActionMask`, `files` etc.

Add `shellScript = "export NODE_BINARY=node\n../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh";`

Here is an example result:

```
SOME_UNIQUE_ID /* Bundle React Native Code And Images */ = {
    isa = PBXShellScriptBuildPhase;
    buildActionMask = SOME_UNIQUE_NUMBER;
    files = (
    );
    inputPaths = (
    );
    name = "Bundle React Native Code And Images";
    outputPaths = (
    );
    runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
    shellPath = /bin/sh;
    /* this is the new line added */
    shellScript = "export NODE_BINARY=node\n../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh\n";
};
```

Now XCode will not crash when expanding the `Bundle React Native codes and images` phase.